# Something wrong in my accelerometer code

Tags: android, accelerometer

I cant find what is wrong here in this code. I am trying to get acceletometer data, but when i try to run it on device it comes out with a message, that process has been shut down.

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {   
SensorManager sm;
Sensor sensor ;
TextView yViewA = null;
TextView zViewA = null;
TextView xViewO = null;
TextView yViewO = null;
TextView zViewO = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


 sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
 xViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xbox);
 yViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ybox);
 zViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zbox);
 xViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xboxo);
 yViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yboxo);
 zViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zboxo);


}    

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sm.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onStop();
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    xViewO.setText("Orientation X: " + event.values[0]);
    yViewO.setText("Orientation Y: " + event.values[1]);
    zViewO.setText("Orientation Z: " + event.values[2]);

}
```

UPD:

```
05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {daler.sensor/daler.sensor.SensorActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1933)

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)

05-18 19:42:17.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

UPD2: Code is updated, still facing problem.
UPD3:Log cat updated

UPD4: I updated the code, now it works. Maybe someone will need it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put `findViewById(R.id.xbox);` in your class body. It should go to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`.

The problem is on line 18 of your code (according to logcat). It's probably this one:

`Sensor sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);`

Because you write:
`SensorManager sm;`
 so the sensor manager is null so you can't use it in `sm.getDefaultSensor()`.

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) to find out how to initalize sensor manager:

```
 public SensorActivity() {
     sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answers im very appreciate it. Unfortunately it still doesnt work. I update logcat.

Comment: You still didn't intialize your SensorManager. See the updated answer

Comment: it gives me error when i put sm = new SensonManager(); under onCreate and there is no more 21 line in logcat after when i moved texviews

Comment: Yeah I didn't know how to initalize it properly, because I never used SensorManager, but checked the documentation and updated the answer again;)

Comment: It really should now. I'm not able to write the whole code because I write from my phone but you should follow the link i gave you, it's exactly what you need. In your class body leave only SensorManager sm; Sensor sensor; and put the code from my answer. It gives you runtime or compile error?

Comment: And you should read logcat messages. It tells you that you don't call super.onCreate() ; in your onCreate() method

Comment: It compiles well and in Eclipse it doesnt show any error. But when it starts on device it gives error Application has been stopped.

Comment: God man you are brilliant. I really now should go outside and relax, how i passed it. Thankss, really. It works now.

Comment: Glad to have helped:-) For the next time - read logcat output carefully, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In you onCreate() try removing the beginning TextView from all those 6 findViewById statements.

change from

```
TextView xViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xbox);
```

to

```
xViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xbox);
```

EDIT:

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

SensorManager sm;
Sensor sensor; 
TextView xViewA = null;
TextView yViewA = null;
TextView zViewA = null;
TextView xViewO = null;
TextView yViewO = null;
TextView zViewO = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 sensor= sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
 sm.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

 xViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xbox);
 yViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ybox);
 zViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zbox);
 xViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xboxo);
 yViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yboxo);
 zViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zboxo);

 setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
..
```

Comment: Upload your latest logcat now.

Comment: Also, what is your line #18 ??

Comment: It doesnt work. I updated log. My line 18 is private  Sensor sensor ;

Comment: I think you need to read the logcat carefully. Call super in onCreate() Like this:
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what i've passed.Thank you.